# Not able to retrieve call Logs specifically through blackberry 10

Tags: html, blackberry-10

I am able to retrieve call Logs through Blackberry-7 but not from blackberry-10 OS.

There are no methods provided to get call logs for blackberry 10 OS.

Is it possible to use methods of blackberry-7 in blackberry-10?

Comment: Take a look [at this documentation](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/api/blackberry.phone.phonelogs.calllog.html). It says this is not supported in BB10. But maybe there is a workaround

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can't do it in WebWorks, but you can add a native extension. I'm sorry that I can't provide you an example, but take a look at [BlackBerry 10: Creating native extensions](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/creating_extensions_for_bb10_apps.html) . From that page:

> Although a BlackBerry WebWorks application has a wide range of functionality, that functionality is limited to the resources that the application contains. By creating a custom extension, you can extend the functionality of your application to include the features and functions provided by core native APIs that are available to BlackBerry 10 OS applications.
>
> You create a custom extension in C/C++, which are the native languages for BlackBerry 10 OS, and then you wrap it in JavaScript. When you build and package your BlackBerry WebWorks application, you include the extension, so that your application can access the extension through JavaScript. You can pass arguments into the extended function and handle return values as you would in any native BlackBerry 10 OS application.